# How to clone jQuery input before delete last value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm copying an input. Each time I copy, the above value comes. If I delete this data, it's all deleted. I just want the last input value to be deleted.

*Here is the code*

```js
function manageEmailButton() {
  var $input = $("input.email-address");

  var c = 0;
  $input.each(function(i, input) {
    if (input.value != '') {
      c++;
    }
  });

  if (c == $input.length) {
    $('.add-extra-email-button').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.add-extra-email-button').attr('disabled', true);
  }
}

$(".email-address").keyup(function(e) {
  manageEmailButton();
});

$(".email-address").change(function(e) {
  manageEmailButton();
});

$('.add-extra-email-button').click(function() {
  $('.div_to_be_cloned').clone(true, true).appendTo('.cloned_div');
  $('.cloned_div .div_to_be_cloned').addClass('single remove');
  $('.single').append('<div class="btn-delete-branch"><button class="remove-field btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></div>');
  $('.cloned_div > .single').attr("class", "remove");

  console.log($(".remove input:last-child").val(""));
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove-field', function(e) {
  $(this).parent('.btn-delete-branch').parent('.remove').remove();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_to_be_cloned">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">E-posta</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control email-address" name="email[]" data-count="" value="" placeholder="E-posta giriniz.." required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text-left">
  <button type="button" class="add-extra-email-button btn btn-success" disabled><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>

<div class="cloned_div"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Dodis, you want to remove this remove-field which is click

Comment: Hi @Dodis, why you trying to remove last item after cloing   console.log($(".remove input:last-child").val(""));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly,

```js
      function manageEmailButton() {
  var $input = $("input.email-address");

  var c = 0;
  $input.each(function(i, input) {
    if (input.value != '') {
      c++;
    }
  });

  if (c == $input.length) {
    $('.add-extra-email-button').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.add-extra-email-button').attr('disabled', true);
  }
}

$(".email-address").keyup(function(e) {
  manageEmailButton();
});

$(".email-address").change(function(e) {
  manageEmailButton();
});

$('.add-extra-email-button').click(function() {
  $('.div_to_be_cloned').clone(true, true).appendTo('.cloned_div');
  $('.cloned_div .div_to_be_cloned').addClass('single remove');
  $('.single').append('<div class="btn-delete-branch"><button class="remove-field btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></div>');
  $('.cloned_div > .single').attr("class", "remove");

  $(".remove:last input:last-child").val('');
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove-field', function(e) {

  $(this).parent('.btn-delete-branch').parent('.remove').remove();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_to_be_cloned">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">E-posta</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control email-address" name="email[]" data-count="" value="" placeholder="E-posta giriniz.." required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text-left">
  <button type="button" class="add-extra-email-button btn btn-success" disabled><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>

<div class="cloned_div"></div>
```